# Is there an elegant way to reset system method names after you reassign them?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

This may be a duplicate but I couldn't find any post about it so if it is, please link me to the post.

If I have a block of code in an ipython notebook:

```
input = input("enter some info")
```

then when I rerun the same block of code, it will give me an error of

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Even if i rename the variable name, I still get the same error. How can I get back the original functionality of the `input` method without needing to restart the entire jupyter notebook?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't set anything to builtin names and functions. Just use another name like `inp` in the first place. If you want to get rid of it, try `del input` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is to not use any system names like `input`, `min`, `max`, etc. Instead use another name entirely, or at least put a trailing underscore: `input_`, `min_`, `max_`. But if it's unavoidable:

IPython's `reset` will reset all names. Example usage:

```
In [1]: input = input("Enter some info: ")
Enter some info: hello

In [2]: input
Out[2]: 'hello'

In [3]: reset
Once deleted, variables cannot be recovered. Proceed (y/[n])? y

In [4]: input
Out[4]: <function input>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not advised to name a variable after a built-in function. But if you insist you can do a placeholder for the original function.

```
input_function = input   # save the input function to another variable
input = input("enter some info")

# do something with the user's input with the input variable (string)

input = input_function   # restore it back
```